# ELL icon in network profile accounts list is outdated

Tags: bug, design

Just now, I was looking through [my network profile's list of accounts](//stackexchange.com/users/5113743/nathan-tuggy?tab=accounts), and noticed a big glaring beta-style icon for ELL. It appears http://cdn.sstatic.net/ell/img/icon-48.png did not get updated, somehow. I refreshed my browser cache, but the old icon is still there. (http://cdn.sstatic.net/ell/img/icon-16.png is also outdated, but I don't know of any place that's actually being used.) Other recently-designed sites, like Crypto, have up-to-date icons with the same URL pattern.

The entry in the [site list](//stackexchange.com/sites) is fine; it uses http://cdn.sstatic.net/ell/img/icon-48.png?v=F2F2E1 instead. Similarly, [our Area 51 listing](//area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched#proposal-summary-41665) is good to go.

Obviously, I'd appreciate this getting fixed along with [my other request](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/bookmark-in-favicon-is-small-and-the-circle-blends-into-backgrounds-too-easily), but this is a clear-cut and (hopefully) simpler bugfix that needs to happen whatever design choices are made.

Comment: @Sally: Huh. I've refreshed, Ctrl-refreshed, and so on and it's still showing the old one.

Comment: @Sally: That seems not unlikely, but usually the cache does not take days to repopulate, so there's probably a glitch somewhere.

Comment: @Sally: Fair enough. Magento is also buggy.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDN cache can indeed take days to update. For example, [Academia design was launched April 23](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/906) in 2014, and a report on outdated icons was made on [April 27th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230586). The issue went away on its own, and I expect this one to do as well.